# How to use SQLite3 to iterate through all results of a query to database

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I'm having difficulty interpreting documentation on this but I currently have a database and I want to iterate through all the elements of a query in a Node.js application using a sqlite3 database.

Is the below how I would access the entry of each row?

```
var query = conn.query(sql, function(error, result){ //sql is a predefined sql statement

    for (var i = 0; i < result.rowCount; i++) {

        result.rows[i];
        }

} );
```

Comment: if you're using sqlLite3 npm module, it appears the npm page has documentation on how to iterate through the result set: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3

Comment: Why have you tagged MYSQL ?